# Would Titan moon blow up if you light a match?

Tags: astronomy, space, moon

Given that the atmosphere of Titan is mostly methane, and from a comment on this [TED talk](http://www.ted.com/talks/charles_elachi_on_the_mars_rovers.html)... Would it blow up from a lighted match-stick?

Seems like it's at *least* plausible. But, wouldn't the lack of oxygen hinder this event? Or perhaps I'm confusing the *blow up* with **combustion**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're quite correct that Titan wouldn't blow up if you struck a match because there is no free oxygen present. In fact the match wouldn't even light.

I watched the Charles Elachi Ted talk and I think the comment about Titan blowing up is just intended as a joke.